# Can I split a $50 coupon from Google Adwords across multiple campaigns?

Tags: google, google-ads

I'm receiving free coupons for Google Adwords
Can I split the $50 into $10 for each website running campaigns? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you absolutely can. Coupons are applied at the account level, and the promotional amount will be deducted as it is spent, independent of how many campaigns that you have.

All billing happens at the account level. Campaigns, although they can have their own unique budget - share against the balance in the account, which is where the coupon is applied to.

Additionally, you can technically use as many coupons as you want, so long that the following criteria are met:

1. The coupon is applied to a Google AdWords Account that was set up less than 14 days prior to the promotional code (coupon) being applied.

The new Google AdWords "Account" does NOT have to be a gmail account, Gsuite account (formerly Google Apps), or an account associated with any Google product prior to signing up for AdWords. Google Adwords allows you to use ANY valid email address to create an account (i.e. yahoo, outlook, mail.com, or your company email), thus the email address does not need to be new.

2. Most commonly, coupons are available after signing up for, and installing Google Analytics on your website, after creating a GMB (Google My Business) location for your business, website, or both, from Direct mail campaigns from Google, as well as from any Google Partner (Ad Agency certified by Google).
3. Advertisers will receive credit to their account after meeting a specific minimum spend, most commonly $25 as of 2017. Funding the account with $25 will not do the trick. You must actually accrue $25 worth of clicks for the credit to be posted to your account.

Technically, you do not need to be a "new advertiser" to take advantage of this promotion. As stated above, you simply need a new Advertising Account. I encourage everyone to not take advantage of this munificent offer, and use the coupon with prudence, along with your moral compass. When used correctly, Google AdWords is a phenomenal tool for any website selling a product or service online.

Answer (score 2):

One customer can only use one coupon [as per AdWords support](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/142741):-

> Promotional codes are typically limited to one per customer, and are
>   often for new advertisers only. Most offers require AdWords accounts
>   to meet certain criteria before credit is applied. Check the terms
>   that came with your promotional code for details about your offer.

Comment: One customer can run multiple campaigns in a single account.   The quote you cite wouldn't preclude using a coupon across several campaigns by the same customer in the same account.